# perform toUpperCase() each time the content of an input field is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, toupper

I want to perform toUpperCase() each time the content of an input field is changed. I mean not when the field lost focus, but each time a character is typed.

I try this which doesn't work (I'm fairly new to JQ)!

```
$(".myClass").change(function () {
        $(this).val().toUpperCase();
});
```

Besides the function is launched only on blur.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.myClass').on('input', function() {
     $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another keyboard event:

https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

```
$( "#test" ).keypress(function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your function is launched on each keystroke, that's fine, but the toUpperCase() doesn't perform! Text remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Function will fire `change` event but You need to reset that value using `.val()` as just setting the text to `toUpperCase()` isn't enough.

```
$(".myClass").change(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PDaVL/)

Answer (score 0):

To limit the characters in the browser input to upper case, use css-

```
someinput{text-transform:uppercase}
```

Then use **any** change event or a validation before submitting to change the value you are sending to the server.